# Improve performance of index search and removal

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a rather simple block of code whose performance I'd like to improve. It consists of a `for` block which uses [np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find indexes of integers in an array.

The code below works, but I feel that using a `for` to add elements to an empty list is not the best way to go about this.

This block is employed by an MCMC so it is executed millions of times. A small improvement turns into a large improvement. Can this be made more efficient?

```
import numpy as np

N = 20
# Integers from 1 to N
ran_indexes = np.random.randint(1, N, 1000)
# Number of integers to remove
rm_number = np.random.randint(0, 100, N)

# Better performance for this block?
# For each integer from 1 to N, keep only 'd' indexes of 'ran_indexes' that
# contain that integer, where 'd' is the ith element in 'rm_number'
new_indexes = []
for i, d in enumerate(rm_number):
    new_indexes += list(np.where(ran_indexes == i + 1)[0][:d])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List joins as you do `+=` are slow, since they require a whole new list each time.  More often when building arrays iteratively we use list append, which is in-place, and only adds on element to the list each time.

```
In [45]:  
    ...: new_indexes = [] 
    ...: for i, d in enumerate(rm_number): 
    ...:     new_indexes.append(np.where(ran_indexes == i + 1)[0][:d]) 
    ...:                                                                        
In [46]: new_indexes                                                            
Out[46]: 
[array([  5,  96, 143, 150, 154, 175]),
 array([ 14,  22,  26,  28,  32,  38,  46,  54,  70, 205, 218, 242, 248,
        254, 271, 318, 344, 352, 357, 393, 419, 437, 448, 472, 473, 503,
        521, 548, 558, 629, 631, 654, 661, 685, 699, 743, 755]),
 array([ 24,  34,  72,  97, 120, 140, 173, 181, 193, 199, 200, 225, 239,
        251, 265, 296, 350, 386, 411, 422, 465, 476, 506, 533, 609, 628,
        680, 694, 713, 759]),
 ....
```

With this construction each array (`where` result) differs in length, with an upper bound from `rm_number`:

```
In [89]: [len(i) for i in new_indexes]-rm_number                                
Out[89]: 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  -2, -24, -40,   0,  -3, -40,
         0, -15,  -5,   0,   0,   0, -96])
```

Variable length arrays/lists like that are good indication that you can't do a super fast 'vectorized' (whole-array) operation, at least not without significant cleverness.

We can get the flat list your code produces with:

```
In [50]: np.concatenate(new_indexes).shape                                      
Out[50]: (626,)
```

Some timings:

```
In [53]: %%timeit  
    ...: new_indexes = [] 
    ...: for i, d in enumerate(rm_number): 
    ...:     new_indexes += list(np.where(ran_indexes == i + 1)[0][:d]) 
    ...:                                                                        

320 µs ± 7.93 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [54]:                                                                        
In [54]: %%timeit 
    ...: new_indexes = [] 
    ...: for i, d in enumerate(rm_number): 
    ...:     new_indexes.append(np.where(ran_indexes == i + 1)[0][:d]) 
    ...:                                                                        

184 µs ± 268 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [55]:                                                                        
In [55]: %%timeit 
    ...: new_indexes = [] 
    ...: for i, d in enumerate(rm_number): 
    ...:     new_indexes.append(np.where(ran_indexes == i + 1)[0][:d]) 
    ...: new_indexes=np.concatenate(new_indexes) 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                        
193 µs ± 622 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [79]: timeit f2()  # Lukas                                                          
291 µs ± 1.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

===

```
temp = ran_indexes[:,None]==np.arange(1,21)
```

finds all matches, and `np.where(temp)[0]` are the indices.  But this doesn't apply your `rm_number` bounds.

```
np.where(temp.T)[1]    # without the `rm_number` truncation  

np.where(temp[:,i])[0][:d]
```

Comment: Selecting this one as it is the fastest implementation. It is faster than my original code by ~15% in my tests while the rest are all below 10%. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Preallocating the space for your `new_indexes` and filling as you go consistently beat appending to an existing list by 20-30% in my test runs, see below for an implementation

```py
def f1():
    new_indexes = []
    for i, d in enumerate(rm_number):
        new_indexes += list(np.where(ran_indexes == i + 1)[0][:d])
    return new_indexes

def f2():
    new_indexes = np.zeros(sum(rm_number))
    ind = 0
    for i, d in enumerate(rm_number):
        tmp = np.where(ran_indexes == i + 1)[0][:d]
        new_indexes[ind:ind+tmp.shape[0]] = tmp
        ind += tmp.shape[0]
    return list(new_indexes[0:ind])


In [144]: %timeit f1
33.5 ns ± 1.71 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [145]: %timeit f2
23.6 ns ± 0.273 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [146]: %timeit f1
35.2 ns ± 3.74 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [147]: %timeit f2
24.5 ns ± 1.47 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

On a side note: the last iteration of either for loop goes without changes and therefore, the last number in `rm_numbers` is never used for anything productive. The maximum number in ran_indexes is 19, and in the last iteration you're checking for `ran_indexes == 19 + 1`, which will always be zero. I'm not sure this is intended, I guess you want to revise your definition of ran_indexes to incorporate `N+1` as the upper bound (given that upper bound is exclusive).
If 19 is indeed supposed to be the highest random number, you should be able to shave off a few nanoseconds by skipping the last loop

Answer (score 1):

Two possible approaches come to my mind - remove for-loop (`f_2` - 30% faster) or use numba (`f_3` - 6x faster). Numba also requires a little bit different approach to the implementation - less python, less work with copying data, more numpy, more work with reading data. Not sure if you can use numba but it worth a try. Alternative to numba is of course Cython. However, Cython requires more refactoring than just wrapping functions with numba.

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

def f_1(ran_indexes, rm_number):
    new_indexes = []
    for idx, qty in enumerate(rm_number):
        new_indexes += list(np.where(ran_indexes == idx + 1)[0][:qty])
    return new_indexes

def f_2(ran_indexes, rm_number):
    return np.hstack([np.where(ran_indexes == idx + 1)[0][:qty] for idx, qty in enumerate(rm_number)])

@nb.njit
def f_3(ran_indexes, rm_number):
    ans = np.zeros(rm_number.sum(), dtype=np.int64)
    count = 0
    for idx in range(rm_number.shape[0]):
        count_2 = 0
        for idx_2 in range(ran_indexes.shape[0]):
            if count_2 == rm_number[idx]:
                break
            if ran_indexes[idx_2] == idx + 1:
                ans[count + count_2] = idx_2
                count_2 += 1
        count += count_2
    return ans[:count]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    N = 20
    ran_indexes_ = np.random.randint(1, N, 1000)
    rm_number_ = np.random.randint(0, 100, N - 1)

    ans_1 = f_1(ran_indexes_, rm_number_)
    ans_2 = f_2(ran_indexes_, rm_number_)
    ans_3 = f_3(ran_indexes_, rm_number_)

    # check results
    print(sum(ans_1), sum(ans_2), sum(ans_3))
    print(len(ans_1), len(ans_2), len(ans_3))
```

Result:

```
%timeit f_1(ran_indexes_, rm_number_)
111 µs ± 279 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit f_2(ran_indexes_, rm_number_)
77 µs ± 118 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit f_3(ran_indexes_, rm_number_)
17 µs ± 6.01 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```